# User changes not saved on SSI XML Source editor

Tags: xml, ssis

user changes are not saved on xml source editor. Mean to say some columns in each output are not used so I am trying to un check them. After saving the changes I tried to edit the XML and I see the changes are not saved. Is this issue Visual studio 2010?

Comment: Could you iterate some more on your question as it is awfully unclear as to what your asking

Comment: I have created a package which has XML as source and I am trying to read only some nodes information from the XML. When I execute the package I get a warning message saying "[SSIS.Pipeline] Warning: The output column "Name" (1243) on output "Switchgear__Children__Part__Relationship__Attribute" (1241) and component "XML Source" (44) is not subsequently used in the Data Flow task. Removing this unused output column can increase Data Flow task performance".
So I tried un checking the columns which are not necessary but after the saving unchecked columns they are still reverting back.